# Can the alchemist adventure during their mummification process?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist, downtime

The Alchemist's [Mummification](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo-alchemist-discoveries/mummification-ex/) discovery states that "the alchemist must perform a 30-day regimen of a special diet, rigorous exercise, and drinking a mildly poisonous alchemical tea."

Can this process be done while adventuring?  Or does the rigorous exercise necessitate this process be undertaken during a month of downtime?

Answer (score 1):

That's one on these cases where the rules are not precise enough. It seems weird to me to detail the process without explaining for example how long must be the exercise each day if it could be performed while adventuring ; for that reason I consider it as a downtime thing.

Ruling it the other way would raise other problems, like how much time exactly you need to use for the regimen, if you can take the "rigorous exercise" if you are wounded... etc.

Answer (score 1):

I concur that the rules aren't clear on the consequences of the process.

With it's description in mind, it sounds like you would be pretty useless during that time. Rigorous exercise could leave you fatigued at the GM's discretion. Mild poison may have some other negative effects (temporary ability score decreases, sickened, blinded, deafened, all options for flavor for a GM).

I would expect you to be sick and have no energy (imagine a chemo patient) for the stretch of 30 days. Having to haul around a 30 day supply of the special diet could also be complicated.

You may be more of a liability than help, but with the wording in mind, I don't see why you can't take the process on the road, provided you make proper arrangements beforehand.